# Is my sieve generalisable?

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test, sieve-theory

I was curious about extending Euler's polynomial generator n^2 - n + 41 for n > 41, and looking for the simplest sieves. I examined the gaps between non-primes and found a set of simple sieves of the form m(k) = m(k-1) + C(k); k=0,1,2.., C(k) = A*k + B, A,B constants, s.t. if n=m(k), then that entry should be discarded. There is one extra new such sieve for each multiple of the range mod 41. For example:
2 <= n <= 40 : all numbers are prime
1*41 <= n < 2*41: gaps between non-primes go as 0,2,4,6,8..
2*41 <= n < 3*41: gaps between non-primes go as 0,1,2,3,4..
3*41 <= n < 4*41: gaps between non-primes go as 0,3,2,7,4,11,6.., which is the interleave of the 2 series 3,7,11.. and 2,4,6..
4*41 <= n < 5*41: gaps between non-primes go as 0,5,2,11,4,17,6.., which is the interleave of the 2 series 5,11,17.. and 2,4,6..
5*41 <= n < 6*41: gaps between non-primes go as 0,7,2,15,4,23,6.., which is the interleave of the 2 series 7,15,23.. and 2,4,6..
and so forth. The rule is that a generated number is prime if all sieves fail to reject it. As n grows, so does the number of sieves. It is clear that the sieves are simply related and are computationally very cheap. It seems perhaps surprising that these simple arithmetic progressions suffice to rid the list of non-primes. The pairwise interleaving I find similarly surprising.

This method generates 100% correctly-sieved primes from n=1 (41) up to n=244 (58847). All non-primes are correctly discarded, and no primes are discarded by the sieves.

However, at n=245, a non-prime is found (59821) which is not discarded. The uniqueness of this non-prime is that its lowest prime factor is not in the sequence, unlike all prior non-primes discarded. I would like to extend this technique but am stuck on n=245. Can anyone afford me some insight?

Comment: [In reply to a now-deleted comment]I mean the polynomial does not generate that prime. The sieve isn't looking for anything like that - it's an algorithm that says e.g. "after 3 more primes, the next number is non-prime". I do not understand the significance of 163 @n=245 but I only point out its uniqueness among all its priors. FYI, these "mongrel" non-primes also form a simple series. Hence my original question about the generalisability of this approach.

Comment: I have now discovered a new pairwise series set very similar to the first set, which explains the above. I still do not know the answer to the generalisability question, but the fact that primes can be sieved using only a set of linearly increasing gaps is intriguing, and seems to point to some deeper result.

Comment: It is very intriguing and I will think more about it later, but for now here is a very easy suggestion for generalization: look if the same works for numbers of the form $n^2 - n + p$ where $p$ is any of the smaller numbers in the (unfortunately finite) set $\{2,3,5,11,17,41\}$. (These are the only numbers for which $n^2 - n + p$ is prime for all $n \in \{1, \ldots, p-2\}$. Of these numbers $41$ is the most famous, but it would be nice to see if the nice structure in the composite numbers of the form $n^2 - n + 41$ also exists for composites of the form $n^2 - n + 17$ or $n^2 - n + 11$.)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heegner_number for (links to) more info on the finite set of 'Euler lucky numbers' $2, 3, 5, 11, 17, 41$.

Comment: In connection with the sieves I define, I am interested to know if there exists a formulaic answer to the question "does this integer quadratic (i.e. with positive integer x and integer coefficients) produce only **composite** integers for all x , 0 to infinity?". The answer, if it exists, would be some formula involving the 3 coefficients.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the full answer to the question "Do all the sieves only produce composite numbers for all $x$ from $0$ to infinity" from the comments. It does not depend on any special property of the number $41$ and hence I will replace the number $41$ with the abstract parameter $p$ in my writings below. By contrast the (seemingly much harder) question "Can we characterize the composites among the numbers not found by these sieves in a equally simple way" of the original post *does* depend on the value of $p$ (at least in some interpretations of the question) and will not be answered here. (Perhaps in a future post.)

Changing notation slightly from my previous post I will write $E(n, p)$ for the numbers of interest, that is $$E(n, p) = n^ 2 - n + p$$

Let me first slightly reformulate the content of the original post. Note for future readers: the OP uses 'gap' in a slightly non-standard way: if the difference $a - b$ between numbers $a$ and $b$ equals $k$ then the gap (in the sense of the OP) equals $k - 1$. (This in contrast to literature where 'gap' and 'difference' are used interchangeably.) I will adopt the notion of gap used in the OP.

For each positive integer $s$ (for starting value) you define a sieve $S_s$ ($S$ for sieve) that, starting at $sp$, finds a series of numbers $n$ such that the corresponding number $E(n, p)$ is composite. The sieve $S_1$ starts at $p$ and finds successive numbers $n$ by jumping over gaps of size $2t$, where $t = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$; For $s \geq 2$ the sieve $S_s$ starts at $sp$ and takes jumps over gaps which are alternatingly taken from the sequences $2t$ ($t = 0, 1, 2\ldots$) and $-1 + 2(s-1)t$ ($t = 1, 2, \ldots$). I will introduce two new families of sieves called $A_s$ and $B_s$ that together cover the same numbers as the sieves $S_s$.

The sieve $A_s$ takes the zeroth, second, fourth, sixth, etc number identified by $S_s$, so it starts at the number $sp$ (which we consider the zeroth term of the sequence found by sieve $A_s$) and to get from its $t$'th term to its $t+1$'th term we need to cross a gap of $[2t] + [1] + [-1 + 2(s-1)(t+1)] =  2st + 2s - 2$.

The sieve $B_s$ takes the first, third, fifth etc number found by $S_s$, so it starts at the number $sp + 1$ (which we consider the first term of the sequence found by sieve $B_s$) and to get from its $t$'th term to its $t + 1$st term we need to jump over a gap of size $[-1 + 2(s-1)t] + 1 + [2t] = 2st$. (Notation is a little bit misleading in that the sequence found by $B_s$ looks that it would grow slower than that found by $A_s$ while in fact it grows faster - the reason is that we start counting at $0$ for $A$ and at $1$ for $B$. However, all this will be resolved by the below lemma.)

The reason I prefer working with $A_s$ and $B_s$ over working with $S_s$ for $s \geq 2$ is that in both new sieves the gaps grow linearly with $t$, just as they do in the sieve $S_1$. When gaps grow linearly, the actual numbers $n$ found by the sieves grow quadratically. The proof of the following lemma is left to the reader:

> **Lemma:**
>
> The numbers $n$ found by the sieve $S_1$ are the numbers $n = p + k^2$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$
>
> The numbers $n$ found by the sieve $A_s$ are the numbers $n = sp + sk(k + 1) - k$, for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$
>
> The numbers $n$ found by the sieve $B_s$ are the numbers $n = (sp + 1) + sk(k+1) + k$ for $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$

We know by definition that the three sieves $S_1, A_s, B_s$ for $s \geq 2$ cover all the numbers found by your sieves $S_s$, $s \geq 1$, but here we also see that if we take the values in the lemma as the *definition* of $A_s$ and $B_s$ for all $s \geq 1$, the sieve $S_1$ can be rewritten as $A_1$. So the sieves $A_s$, $s \geq 1$ and $B_s$, $s \geq 2$ together cover all the numbers found by your sieves $S_s$. Even nicer: the numbers produced by the sieve $B_1$ are of the form $sp + k^2 + 2k + 1 = sp + (k + 1)^2$ so they are all also covered by the sieve $A_1$. In other words, we lose nothing by simply stating that the numbers $n$ found by your sieves $S_s$ for $s \geq 1$ are the same numbers as those found by the sieves $A_s$ and $B_s$ for $s \geq 1$.

This concludes my reformulation of your post. Now for the new result:

> **Theorem:**
>
> - The numbers $E(n, p)$ where $n = sp + sk(k+1) - k$ is produced by sieve $A_s$ decompose as $$E(sp + sk(k+1) - k , p) = E(k+1, p)E(sk, s^2p - s + 1)$$ and hence are all composite. Note that in the special case $s = 1$ this reduces to the formula found in the previous answer.
> - The numbers $E(n, p)$ where $n = sp + 1 + sk(k+1) + k$ is produced by sieve $B_s$ decompose as $$E(sp + 1 + sk(k+1) + k, p) = E(k+1, p)E(sk + 2, s^2p + s - 1)$$ and hence are all composite as well. Note that, again, this is consistent with the formula found in the first answer since the $k$'th number found by $B_1$ sieve equals (as remarked before) the $k+1$st number found by the $S_1$ sieve and subsituting $s = 1$ in the right hand side of last formula gives $E(k+1, p)E(k+2, p)$ which of course equals $E((k+1)+1, p)E(k+1, p)$, which was the decomposition found in the previous answer of the $k+1$st number found by the $S_1$ sieve.

*Proof of the first statement:* write out the definitions of the terms and then expand out all the brackets. The resulting expressions at the left and rigth of the equality sign will be equal.
*Proof of the second statement:* do the same but now with these sligtly different expressions.

(Sorry for the lazy form of proof-writing, but I am sure I will make typos when I try to do it here.)

Generally speaking: proving the validity of such a decomposition is easy but finding it is not. However in this case I was greatly helped by your remark that in all these cases the smallest prime factor was of the form $E(n, p)$ again. Looking at the theorem we see that this need not always be true: YES every number $E(N, p)$ found by the sieve is divisible by some $E(n, p)$ ($n < N$), but whenever this latter number $E(n, p)$ has a smallest prime factor that is itself not of the form $E(k, p)$ OR when the smallest prime factor of the *other* factor of $E(N, p)$ given by the theorem is not of the form $E(k, p)$ *and* smaller than the smallest factor of $E(n, p)$ then the smallest prime factor of $E(N,p)$ need not be of the form $E(k, p)$.

I must say that I am still a bit surprised that, as in the previous answer, both terms in the decomposition are of the form $E(n, p)$ although the small price we have to pay is that we need to treat the parameter $p$ on equal footing as the parameter $n$, in the sense that both are allowed to change. The whole thing is really fascinating!

Comment: Thank you Vincent; it all looks very reasonable although I still need to check the detail. I had already derived quadratic equivalent expressions back in 2013, but had not come up with this neat generalisation of the composite property proof. Now I think it's time to remind you of the original question. Since you've generalised my sieves, you must also get the same problem I ran into at $E(245,41) = 59,821 = 163*367$ whereby neither prime factor belongs to $E(n,41)$, and thus (I think) your sieve will also fail. Do I misunderstand? I know I'm jumping ahead a bit here, pending my detail checks.

Comment: No you understand correctly. My sieves produce exactly the same numbers as yours in the case of $p = 41$ and hence will miss $E(245, 41)$ for exactly the reason you state. The original question is whether there is a more general sieve of roughly the same form that catches ALL composites, isn't it? I am a bit skeptical, but can  not see an easy way to rule it out either. I will think about it.

Comment: As I mention in the original comments, I found a way to continue past $E(245,41)$ without missing it, but it's not to hand and I'l have to dig. If I recall correctly, again we establish a pair of interleaved sieves and keep on going, using both the old pair and the new pair. Since the Heegener number 163 is so special, I don't think there are any more exceptions. At least now you can see how interesting is this set of sieves! They always generate a composite which needs rejection (never one that does not), they never miss one, and they never coincide. I find this complete cover extraordinary.

Comment: I understand now how Robert Israel's sieve from the OEIS-comment works. In slightly different notation: if $n$ is a divisor (not necessarily prime!) of $E(m, p)$ then apparently $E(m, p) == 0 mod n$. Since, for every $k$, the numbers $m$ and $m + kn$ are congruent ("indistinguishable") modulo $n$ we see that $E(m, p)$ and $E(m + kn, p)$ are congruent modulo $n$ as well, hence $E(m + kn, p) == 0 mod n$, hence $n$ divides $E(m + kn, p)$. Starting with $n = E(m, p)$ this produces an avalanche of composites. First all the numbers $E(m + kE(m, p), p)$ that are apparently divisible by $E(m, p)$...

Comment: ...but then also for every $k$ we have that $E(m + k E(m, p), p)/E(m, p)$ is a divisor of some $E(M, p)$ (namely $M = m + k E(m, p)$) and hence can be taken as a 'new' $n$ which produces its own infinite sequence of composites. And all this starting only with a single element $E(m, p)$. But we could do this for all $m$! I think a good first step would be to check if all these many many elements can be parametrized in a nicer algebraic way and in how far they are already covered by your sieves. And then of course the question is if $E(245, 41)$ is caught by one of these R. Israel sieves or not.

Comment: Yes! I went to sleep feeling stupid about the Israel idea (even after having read his email reply, a 1-line restatement) but just woke and it's obvious (lol). But I had not got as far as you with the avalanche idea here. I think you realised this property immediately based on your initial reaction to Israel's comment. I'll be looking at this later. But I would point out that most of these Israel composites lie very high up in the composite sequence compared to s=5 so far. Still, Israel *has* defined a new sieve.

Comment: One key question is whether the Israel sieve produces full cover of all composites, like my sieves (almost) do. I think that it does not, because it seems sparser. This is unclear to me currently.

Comment: Just a note that the existence of the Israel composites constitutes part of the general proof that no non-constant polynomial exists capable of generating only primes.

Comment: Yes this last remark is very true. Israel's construction works for every polynomial and hence shows that every polynomial produces composites. However the question remains if there is one polynomial for which his construction covers all composites generated by that polynomial and if so if $n^2 -n + 41$ is such a polynomial. I share your intuition about sparsity, but we have to think more about it. In the long term Israel's sieves become less sparse than any single one of yours since it grows linear rather than quadratic. But you produce new sieves at a linear rate which fully compensates that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72976/discussion-between-andrew-palfreyman-and-vincent).

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer: a special case of the question in your last comment rather than the post itself. If I can find the time I will do a few other special cases of that question in the following days. (Or perhaps this answer puts you on track to do it yourself.) After that I hope we can guess the general pattern behind it.

The question only came really alive for me after I computed the distribution of primes and composites in the sequence $\{E_n := n^2 - n + 41, n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots \}$ myself, I recommend future readers to do the same. (Notation $E_n$ is non-standard, but I don't believe there is a standard notation and it helps if we have *some* notation for these numbers. $E$ for Euler of course.) One obvious pattern which you only mention implicitly is that for every integer $k > 0$ the numbers $E_{41k}$ and $E_{41k + 1}$ are composite. Here the reason is fairly obvious: $E_{41k} = 41^2k^2 - 41k + 41 = 41*(41k^2 - k + 1)$ and $E_{41k+1} = 41^2k^2 + 2*41*k + 1 - 41k - 1 + 41 = 41(41k^2 + k + 1)$.

Let's see if we can find a similar argument for the more impressive patterns you do mention. The first of these is the observation that, starting at $n =    41$ (which is composite by the above), composites appear when jumping over $0, 2, 4$, etc numbers in between, so at $n = 41 + 1, 41 + 1 + 3, 41 + 1 + 3 + 5, \ldots$ In other words: the numbers caught by the first sieve are the numbers $E_{41 + k^2}$ where $k$ runs over $0, 1, 2, \ldots$. You seem to claim that these are all composite, even if after some point (more precisely: from $n = 2*41$ onwards) not all the numbers in between are prime. Let's see if we can confirm that algebraically.

$$E_{41 + k^2} = (41 + k^2)^2 - (41 + k^2) + 41 = $$
$$k^4 + 2*41*k^2 + 41^2 - 41 - k^2 + 41 = $$
$$k^4 + (2*41-1)*k^2 + 41^2.$$

With its form '$k^4$ plus some big number times $k^2$ plus the square of something else' it looks pretty much the same as '$(k^2 + $ something $)^2$'. It is not quite the same, probably, but we can always see how close it gets. The best guess for the 'something' is $41$, in that way we do at least get the first and third term right. So, lets calculate and see what happens:

$(k^2 + 41)^2 = k^4 + 2*41*k^2 + 41^2$

Aha! A very near miss! $(k^2 + 41)^2 - E_{41 + k^2}$ is only $1*k^2 = k^2$! But now we observe something even nicer. Obviously $k^2$ is a square. So rewriting the above as $E_{41 + k^2} = (k^2 + 41)^2 - k^2$ we can use the formula for 'remarkable products' (this is a translation from Dutch, I don't know the proper English term, but I mean the formula $A^2 - B^2 = (A + B)(A - B)$) to show that all these numbers are indeed composite:

$$E_{41 + k^2} = (k^2 + 41 + k)(k^2 + 41 - k) = E_{k+1}E_k$$

Wow! This is even better than I anticipated! Not only does it show the numbers caught by the first sieve are all composite, they can all be written as a product of two other elements in the sequence $E_n$!

It would be nice if it turns out that the latter is true for all your sieves, but I really have to go  to bed now so we have to figure that out later. Thanks for the nice question, though!

Comment: Yes, thank you, I corrected it in the post.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A007634 lists composites for the related series $n^2 +n +41$. The comment by Robert Israel is interesting. Also https://oeis.org/A055390 derives your result in the comment by Anderson.

Comment: I only see this now, after writing the other answer. The comment by Robert Israel (who is also very active here at MSE) is indeed very interesting. It seems to give  way to create an infinite sequence of composites starting with just one. It would be nice to understand this better.

Comment: Before I process and respond to your answer, I offer this http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath263.htm which shows that the "central sequence" of primes for the Heegner number 163 is precisely Euler's $E_n$ for $1<=n<=11$

Answer (score 0):

Let $E(n, p) = n^ 2 - n + p$.  Then

**Theorem:**

- The numbers $E(n_A,p)$, where $n_A = sp + sk(k+1) − k$ are produced by sieve $A_s$, decompose as
  $$E(n_A,p) = E(k+1,p) * (s^2E(k+1,p) - s(2k + 1) + 1)$$
- The numbers $E(n_B,p)$, where $n_B = (sp+1) + sk(k+1) + k$ are produced by sieve $B_s$, decompose as
  $$E(n_B,p) = E(k+1,p) * (s^2E(k+1,p) + s(2k + 1) + 1)$$

I've checked this for $p=41, s=1,2,3$ and $k=0,1,2,3$.